# Laravel {!! nl2br(e($value)) !!} is unsafe?

Tags: php, laravel, security, xss

When I want to output values via Blade about

- Text including newline codes (such as \lf)
- Visible newline codes with (such as a BR tag or a pre tag)

They say that I need to use `{!! nl2br(e($value)) !!}` .

It is a very clear way to do this, and I understand that it is not a security issue.
However, I think the problem is that you have to remember to use "raw", "nl2br" and "e()" all together.
If you forget any of these, you have an XSS vulnerabilities.

When there are included in a large application, code review may not find the incorrect usage.
Is there any way to achieve this with the basic functionality of the template engine?

I am thinking of using the pre tag.

Comment: You could create your own blade directive, like `@htmlsafe($value)` that internally does `{!! nl2br(e($value)) !!}`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#extending-blade, or look at PHP's `strip_tags` method to remove certain unsafe HTML tags from `$value` (like `<script>` for example), etc etc.

Comment: which laravel version do you use?